# In Linux, how can I find all sub-folders within a specific directory that do not contain a specific file?

Tags: linux, find

I need to be able to find all sub-directories that are missing a specific file.

I have thousands of zip files that are being Ftp'd to my server within a specific directory on a daily basis:
/opt/FTP/IN
Now the sender is creating folders under that directory and placing zip files within the folders being created, there could be hundreds to thousands of folders created. However, when they are done placing zip files in a specific folder, they are supposed to create a file called done.txt to let us know that folder is ready to be processed. Sometimes they miss placing the done.txt file and I need to go in and manually create it.

How can I search for and only collect the folder names that do not contain the done.txt file?

Comment: Do the directories have any sort of tree structure, is it all flat?

Answer (score 4):

Whichever is clearer to you:

Invert the `find` condition:

```
find /start/dir -type d ! -exec test -e {}/done.txt \; -print
```

Invert the `test` condition:

```
find /start/dir -type d -exec test ! -e {}/done.txt \; -print
```

Any directories that don't have a `done.txt` file in them are the printed.

Comment: "Fail the test" might be confusing wording; hopefully the intention is clear.

Comment: If you're using `{}` anyway, is `-execdir` needed?

Comment: Good point, @muru - thanks! I had started off initially thinking I needed to use execdir, but exec works perfectly. I'll update the Answer.